# How can i fix my 404 error when trying to access assets in my s3 bucket using remix and aws cdk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am using remix.run and aws cdk to develop my website, however I am finding that my site assets such as my site logo get a 404 in my browser console when I access my cloudfront deployment. I can see my assets in my s3 bucket in the aws console I just cannot access when on my site.

Here is my aws cdk code:

```
export class AppStack extends Stack {
  public distribution: Distribution;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const assetsBucket = new Bucket(this, "assets-bucket", {
      autoDeleteObjects: true,
      publicReadAccess: false,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    const assetsBucketOriginAccessIdentity = new OriginAccessIdentity(
        this,
        "AssetsBucketOriginAccessIdentity"
    );

    const assetsBucketS3Origin = new S3Origin(assetsBucket, {
      originAccessIdentity: assetsBucketOriginAccessIdentity,
    });

    assetsBucket.grantRead(assetsBucketOriginAccessIdentity);

    const entry = path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'index.ts');

    const dynamoTable = new Table(this, 'application-table', {
      partitionKey: {
        name: 'id',
        type: AttributeType.STRING,
      },
      sortKey: {
        name: 'formType',
        type: AttributeType.STRING,
      },
      billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    dynamoTable.addGlobalSecondaryIndex({
      indexName: 'formTypeIndex',
      partitionKey: { name: 'formType', type: AttributeType.STRING },
      sortKey: { name: 'id', type: AttributeType.STRING },
    });

    // S3 bucket
    const pdfBucket = new Bucket(this, "PdfBucket", {
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY, // NOT recommended for production code
    });

    const lambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "remix-function", {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      currentVersionOptions: {
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      },
      memorySize: 1024,
      logRetention: RetentionDays.THREE_DAYS,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
      entry,
      environment: {
        DYNAMO_TABLE_NAME: dynamoTable.tableName,
        PDF_BUCKET_NAME: pdfBucket.bucketName,
      },
    });

    dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(lambda);
    pdfBucket.grantReadWrite(lambda);
    assetsBucket.grantReadWrite(lambda);

    const api = new apigateway.HttpApi(this, 'http-api', {
      defaultIntegration: new HttpLambdaIntegration('http-integration', lambda),
    });

    const apiUri = api.url?.replace('https://', '').split('/')[0] ?? '';

    const apiOrigin = new HttpOrigin(apiUri, {
      protocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
    });

    // Managed-AllViewerExceptHostHeader, not yet in CDK static options
    const originRequestPolicy = OriginRequestPolicy.fromOriginRequestPolicyId(this, 'request-policy', 'b689b0a8-53d0-40ab-baf2-68738e2966ac');

    this.distribution = new Distribution(this, "distribution", {
      defaultBehavior: {
        allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
        cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
        compress: true,
        origin: apiOrigin,
        originRequestPolicy: originRequestPolicy,
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      },
      additionalBehaviors: {
        "build/*": {
          allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_GET_HEAD,
          cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_OPTIMIZED,
          compress: true,
          origin: assetsBucketS3Origin,
          viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
        },
      },
    });

    new BucketDeployment(this, "AssetsDeployment", {
      destinationBucket: assetsBucket,
      distribution: this.distribution,
      prune: true,
      sources: [Source.asset("../remix/public")],
      cacheControl: [
        CacheControl.maxAge(Duration.days(365)),
        CacheControl.sMaxAge(Duration.days(365)),
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

I dont know exactly why it seems to be failing, I think it may be a permission error as I tried to run a few commands to test my s3 access such as:
aws s3api list-objects --bucket assets-bucket --prefix modern-museum-monogram.png

But I get an:
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Any help or pointers would be amazing! Thanks!